# Diagram of equivalences in modular representation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Years ago I had found (and printed) a big list of all equivalences used in modular representation theory (and block theory), with arrows denoting the various implications (for instance, Morita equivalence -> Derived equivalence). At the top there were strong things like isomorphism of source algebras, and at the bottom "Isomorphism of centers" and "$k(B)=k(C)$" (the number of ordinary characters in the block).

It was a vertical diagram, with many ramifications and, I'd say, more than $20$ different properties listed.

Sadly, due to the lockdown that diagram is now on the wall of my office in a building closed until further notice... and I was not able to find it again. Long shot, but does anyone know what I am talking about? I am 99% sure that it was part of a survey paper, or a survey chapter in a book. It was really detailed and well done.